# sencha modern list item swipe item bug

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I'm trying to provide swipe actions in Sencha Modern list in version 7.2.0.

Although the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.dataview.listswiper.Item.html) indicates that the text, ui, iconcls and cls are bindable, I'm unable to get it to work.

Further, the text seems to be getting bound without any bind configuration which is even more surprising.

Please see relevant [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com#view/editor&fiddle/3aiv)

Essentially, I would like to make the iconCls and the cls change based on the record's data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely an issue here.  The text does not seem to be handled as a bind.  If the text field exists it is used..... so I did a quick override that treats the ui field similarly.  if it exists it is using it.  You can do the same with the iconCls... etc.

[Swipper override fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3al2)